# Fill in External Item Picker (BDC) with query string value with InfoPath

Tags: infopath, bcs, query-string, bdc

We are trying to customize a 'new' form with InfoPath so that our query string value (idPatient) is automatically filled in into the External Item Picker (BDC entity).

In InfoPath, we have set up the following:

[image]

A field **idPatient** linked to the *idPatient* property.
An External Item Picker linked to the BDC Entity *Patients*.

We have promoted property *idPatient* so we can connect a Query String filter webpart on our page to this property.

If we go to our form, e.g.  /newifs.aspx?idPatient=123, we get following result:

[image: Form with filled in idPatient]

As you can see, in the first field, the value is loaded perfectly. However, in the External Item Picker, we don't find a way to get the id inserted.

We tried to add the group as a promoted property, but we get an error message that 'Groups are not supported as Web Part connection parameters'.

Is there any way to get our query string value in our Exteral Item Picker?

PS: the External Item Picker works as intended when manually filling in an id

Thanks in advance!